# Key Error : 'image' while adding new column to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing a CNN project on google colab and I have uploaded the image dataset in google drive. After reading csv file for labels I have created a dataframe whose first five elements are as below:

```
    image   level
0   10_left   0
1   10_right  0
2   13_left   0
3   13_right  0
4   15_left   1
```

Now I need to create a column 'path' which contains path of each image.

```
base_image_dir = 'My Drive/Fist500'
import os
df['path'] = df['image'].map(lambda x: os.path.join(base_image_dir,'{}.jpg'.format(x)))
```

However on running this I get following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'image'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
2 frames
<ipython-input-72-cacf7c6ca99e> in <module>()
      1 base_image_dir = 'My Drive/Fist500'
      2 import os
----> 3 df['path'] = df['image'].map(lambda x: os.path.join(base_image_dir,'{}.jpg'.format(x)))
      4 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'image'
```

Comment: This is a standard `pandas` question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: `'image'` is not a column name. Make sure there is no leading or trailing white space: `'image '`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but reading `os.path` into a string will lose it's object status - so just do simple string concatenation.

Comment: You need to set path for this folder use files=glob.glob (*.jpeg) and then appen to column paths for those files , use for file in files :